# Well readable error?

Tags: php

If i have a c1.php

```
<?php
class C1 {
    function f1($value) {
        if($value == 'ok') {
            echo "OK!";
        } else {
            throw new Exception("WRONG!");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and index.php

```
<?php
require_once('c1.php');
$c = new C1();
$c->f1('ok');
$c->f1('asd');
?>
```

Can anybody know, how to construct a well readable error message like "Error: you have wrong value in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\index.php: line 5" instead of tracktracing

```
OK!
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'WRONG!' in
C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\c1.php:7 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\index.php(5): C1->f1('asd') #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\c1.php on line 7
```

that reading is a little difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Catch the exception. This is the point of exceptions.. they are catchable and you can do something with the information (for instance.. output just the message).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
try {
    $c = new C1();
    $c->f1('ok');
    $c->f1('asd');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: you have wrong value in ', $e->getFile(), ' on line ', $e->getLine();
    // ... code
}
```

Comment: I know the try and catch, but how to show the exact loccation (file and line) of calling like "$c->f1('asd');". Thank you.

Comment: @iff This is what Exception::getFile() and Exception::getLine() functions return, the file and the line where the Exception was throw. See [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)

Answer (score 0):

i caught it

```
try {
    ..
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        $t = $e->getTrace();
        $t = $t[0];
        echo 'Error: file - ',$t['file'],' - line: ',$t['line'],
                  ' - function: ',$t['function'],'; ',$e->getMessage();
}
```

thank you for hints.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, don't use an exception.  They should be used when you're doing a try-catch or for an exceptional situation.  This is not exceptional - meaning nothing can possibly turn an error with just a if-else statement.

So just echo out the error message of your choice.